# How to implement data table slot group.summary in Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetifyjs3

Is there a way to implement similar functionality as group.summary in vuetify 3?
In Vuetify 2 we can use #group.summary slot to to add summary to table grouping. Is there a way to do the same thing in Vuetify 3?

Comment: assuming the [documentation](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots) is correct, no, it's not implemented in Vuetify 3 yet.  You might find more information regarding it's status or if it's being developed by asking on the Vuetify github or one of their social platforms.